# Generate Variables Through T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

Is it possible to generate variables solely through code?  If you have a base variable name, and add an int to the end of the name, could you generate variables?  Something similar to the below?

In the end I would want this syntax to generate 4 variables

> ```
> @newlygeneratedvariable1
> @newlygeneratedvariable2
> @newlygeneratedvariable3
> @newlygeneratedvariable4
> ```

```
Declare @i int, @totalvariables int

Set @totalvariables = '4'

for @i <= 4
Set @i = 1

    Declare @newlygeneratedvariable + @i 
    Print 

    @i = @i + 1

Next @i
```

Comment: I'm interested in what problem you are trying to solve. You can not create variables dynamically. You can however create code dynammicly but the best solution for you is probably to use a temp table.

Comment: I can't imagine why you'd want to do this unless it's just being lazy or you've got a design issue. Use a 2-column temporary table instead: attribute, value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
DECLARE @i INT = 1
DECLARE @totalvars INT = 5
DECLARE @newvar VARCHAR(50) = ''

WHILE @i < @totalvars

BEGIN

SET @newvar = 'DECLARE @newvar' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @i) + ' = ?;'

SET @i += 1

RAISERROR (@newvar, 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT;

END
```

So we're all clear, this won't create variables for you unless it's part of a larger block of dynamic SQL. You're probably better off using a temp table. But on the off chance you're using more dynamic SQL, you could use a loop like this to append the variable declarations just fine.